# GET http://localhost/Grafica/%7Bd.icon%7D/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a tooltip in a meteogram , and I want to show the image of the state of the sky . This is my code html

```
<div id="tooltip">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr><th>Hora (local)</th><th data-text="d.datetime | date">{d.datetime}</th></tr>
        <tr class="avg"><td>Temperatura </td><td data-text="d.temp | temp">{d.temp}</td></tr>
        <tr class="rain"><td>Precipitaci&oacute;n </td><td data-text="d.rain | rain">{d.rain} </td></tr>
        <tr class="wind"><td>Velocidad del viento </td><td data-text="d.wind_speed | wind">{d.wind_speed}</td></tr>
        <tr class="wind"><td>Direcci&oacute;n del viento </td><td data-text="d.wind_direcion | degree">{d.wind_direction}</td></tr>
        <tr class="pressure"><td>Presi&oacute;n</td><td data-text="d.pressure | pressure">{d.pressure} </td></tr>
        <tr class="hum"><td>Humedad</td>><td data-text="d.humidity | percent">{d.humidity} </td></tr>
        <tr class="cloud"><td>Nubes</td><td data-text="d.cloud | percent">{d.cloud} %</td></tr>
        <tr class="snow"><td>Nieve</td><td data-text="d.snow | snow">{d.snow} mm</td></tr>
        <tr class="sky"><td>Estado Cielo</td><td><img src={d.icon}/></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is the part where I link scrip data

```
var ttobj = {d:{}};
rivets.bind($('#tooltip'), ttobj);

if(config.graphic.tooltip){
        d3.select('#tooltip')
            .attr('style', 'display: block; top:'+(ty+10)+'px;left:'+(tx+10)+'px');
        // update the rivets tt obj
        for(key in d) { 
            var value =0.0;
            if(key == 'icon'){
                value = "images/icons/"+d[key]+".png";
```

I have this error GET http://localhost/Grafica/%7Bd.icon%7D/ 404 (Not Found)
and do not know how to put it in the html to leave me the picture

Comment: So where is this link? Is it the `{d.icon}`?

Comment: for example: http://localhost/Grafica/images/icons/rain.png, {d.icon} return the image's name

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<tr class="sky"><td>Estado Cielo</td><td><img src={d.icon}/></td></tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr class="sky"><td>Estado Cielo</td><td><img src="{d.icon}"/></td></tr>
```

You missed out the quotes for the *src* attribute.

Comment: It looks like the placeholder isn't replace (by whatever templating engine is in use), as `{d.icon}` is probably not the real image path. So this still won't work.

Comment: If I put <tr class="sky"><td>Estado Cielo</td><td><img>{d.icon}<img/></td></tr>, {d.icon} is the real image path